# I can't get Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm trying to create a dual boot machine with Windows 10 and Ubuntu.  I managed to install Windows and shrink the drive to make space for Ubuntu and then I managed to install Ubuntu fine.  However, I don't get a grub screen with both the Windows and Ubuntu option.  I changed the boot order of Windows and Ubuntu so Ubuntu was first.  I disabled legacy boot from BIOS and at least a grub menu appeared however it didn't show the windows option.  I re-installed grub from a terminal in Ubuntu using the command:

```
install-grub /dev/sda
```

and then updated it using the command:

```
update grub
```

And got an error in the output you can see in the screenshot.  What else can I do to achieve my goal, I'd be grateful for any help anybody can give?

[image]

Regards

Nick

Comment: that `os-prober` doesn't run by default in new Ubuntu releases has been in the news (sort of). You may need to edit `/etc/default/grub`and add a line like `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`.

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive? And then is Windows fast startup/hibernation off.